# Keyboard Shortcut To Insert Command in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, keyboard

Does anyone know of a simple way to map a command to an unused keyboard shortcut so that when I press the shortcut when typing in the terminal it inserts the command? Specifically I'm looking to quickly execute the series of commands

```
make; sudo make install; sudo ldconfig
```

It's not a long command, but I end up typing it about 100 times a day. The ideal solution would work in any directory and would be automatically mapped on startup. OS is Ubuntu 12.10. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script, then save that file's directory in your PATH

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables

Answer (score 0):

Use a bash alias.

Put a line like this in your .bashrc, .bash_profile, or any file sourced in one of these. I have a separate file for aliases called .bash_aliases.

```
alias fullmake="make; sudo make install; sudo ldconfig"
```

Then you can just run fullmake in a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to try https://github.com/dvorka/hstr which allows for "suggest box style" filtering of Bash history with (optional) metrics based ordering:

[image]

It can be easily bound to <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd> - therefore you can insert to command prompt recently (and often) used commands  quickly.